# Split NSString and Limit the response

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a string Hello-World-Test, I want to split this string by the first dash only.

String 1:Hello
String 2:World-Test

What is the best way to do this? What I am doing right now is use componentsSeparatedByString, get the first object in the array and set it as String 1 then perform substring using the length of String 1 as the start index.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I added a category on `NSString` to split on the first occurrence of a given string. It may not be ideal to return the results in an array, but otherwise it seems fine. It just uses the `NSString` method `rangeOfString:`, which takes an `NSString`(B) and returns an `NSRange` showing where that string(B) is located.

```
@interface NSString (Split)

- (NSArray *)stringsBySplittingOnString:(NSString *)splitString;

@end

@implementation NSString (Split)

- (NSArray *)stringsBySplittingOnString:(NSString *)splitString
{
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString:splitString];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%li",range.location);
        NSLog(@"%li",range.length);
        NSString *string1 = [self substringToIndex:range.location];
        NSString *string2 = [self substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];
        NSLog(@"String1 = %@",string1);
        NSLog(@"String2 = %@",string2);
        return @[string1, string2];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `rangeOfString` to find if `split string exits` and then use `substringWithRange` to `create new string` on bases of `NSRange`.

For Example :

```
 NSString *strMain = @"Hello-World-Test";
 NSRange match = [strMain rangeOfString:@"-"];
if(match.location != NSNotFound)
{

    NSString *str1 = [strMain substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (0, match.location)];
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
    NSString *str2 = [strMain substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (match.location+match.length,(strMain.length-match.location)-match.length)];
    NSLog(@"%@",str2);
}
```

Comment: Why call rangeOfString twice? Call it once and save the location. And it would be easier to use substringFromIndex and substringToIndex to get the two substrings.